# Python Selenium switch to pane

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm new to selenium. After my initial login, I need to access (send focus to) a certain panel ("naviatePane") and then expand a tree structure:

```
<div id="navigatePane" class="pane" style="height: 312.9px;">
<div id="finderTree"><div class="ygtvitem" id="ygtv11"><div class="ygtvchildren" id="ygtvc11"><div class="ygtvitem" id="ygtv12">
```

I don't have a great understanding of JS but I have tried:

```
for handle in driver.window_handles:
  print handle
```

In order to try and find a name that I can reference to no avail. And:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='navigatePane']//navigatePane[@class='pane']")
```

But I probably don't have syntax down correctly.

Comment: Which element you want to handle? Describe as User what you intend to do on page

Comment: I would like to click on the "navigationPane" and then select the "<div class="ygtvitem" id="ygtv11">" element. Which would expand the "+"  button in the tree and then select an element from there

Comment: AFAIK there is no `navigationPane` tag in `HTML`. If you mean `<div id="navigatePane" class="pane">` then I'm not sure that you could click on it to trigger drop-down menu. Provide extended `HTML` code for mentioned element

Comment: Clicking on the navigationPane does not activate a drop-down menu, I only need the focus to be on the box which is titled "navigationPane". The click tree is already populated in the navigationPane when it is selected. If this is not enough code let me know, thanks: select the <td id="ygtvcontentel10" class=" ygtvcontent"><span id="ygtvlabelel10" class="ygtvlabel">Object to Select</span></td>

Comment: is there any `<input>`, `<button>` or `<a>` elements?

Comment: I don't see any of those elements in the page source, all I have is:    <span class="inactive" id="btnFinder">Finder</span>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126623/discussion-between-andersson-and-namor).